# How to access winforms data from wpf interop?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

There are 2 projects in my Solution.

```
-WindowsFormsApplication8
-WpfControlLibrary1
```

I am using ElementHost from WPF Interoperability to host UserControl1 from the WpfControlLibrary1.

```
_________________________
Form1             - [] x |
-------------------------

  ..........
  | label1 |  // label
  ..........

// elementHost1 
// wpf control has one 
// button and nothing else
   ____________
  |            |
  |  ClickMe1  |
  |____________|

__________________________
```

Now,

```
<Canvas>
    <Button Click="btnclick">hello</Button>
</Canvas>

private void btnclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(); // this msgbox
}
```

I want "this msgbox" to show contents of label1.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my answer. This site is usefull for you to do both ways:

http://sachabarber.net/?p=149

Comment: @pipelinecache Please post an example I am too dumb to understand without it!! :)

Comment: Hi David, yes I can, It will cost me just a few minutes. Hold on.

Comment: Thanks, I only wish I had more time to do some blogging.